# Python socked bound to secondary IP gets connection reset from server

Tags: python, sockets, tcpdump

I'm trying to create a python socket script that binds to a secondary IP 
and connects to a server. When I run the script python gives me a
"socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused"

The TCPdump shows that the server I try to connect to sends back a reset response. Running the
script without the socket.bind works.

The script:

```
import socket
port = 9009
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("123.123.123.123", port)) # Not the real IP I use
sock.connect(("81.236.48.66", 80)) # Raises connection refused
```

The tcpdump:

```
11:22:08.211502 IP 123.123.123.123.9009 > 81.236.48.66.80: Flags [S], seq 3687363746, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1304421782 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
11:22:08.211763 IP 81.236.48.66.80 > 123.123.123.123.9009: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3687363747, win 5840, length 0
```

I run the script on a linux box and the secondary IP I use is listen when I use the command: "ip list all"

Thanks in advance and please bear with me since I'm not very experienced in socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The firewall was configured to block the response and sent a reset flag.